# Nginx two-way authentication between two play services

Tags: ssl, nginx, mutual-authentication

I have two remote servers that run two play framework services (client, server) and I want to configure SSL mutual Authentication between them.

Iam using Nginx as a reverse proxy to the server and Iam trying to use Nginx as forward proxy in front of the client.

The reverse proxy works perfectly and I tested it by importing the client certificate to a browser and tested authentication. My problem in the client server I need to configure Nginx on the client server as forward proxy to send the client certificate in its request.

Can Nginx do that (I googled a lot and I can't find a way). Or will I have to use Apache or squid as forward proxy?
Is there a better way to do the mutual SSl Authentication between the two servers?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx doesn't support two-way/mutual authentication using client cert/key.

I have added support for mutual auth for connecting to upstream weblogic server.

See the patch details:

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/pull/7
http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2014-August/005817.html